# Search a filename with timestamp using regex

Tags: c#, regex, csv

I have a function that reads a file from a specified folder. It uses a xml file to get the filename and its path.
It worked fine when the filename was Finance.csv, but now the requirement changed and  the filename has a timestamp (Finance_May2016.csv) and the config file has the following

```
<filename>Finance_{Date:mmmYYYY}.csv <\filename>
<Path> C:\folder <\Path>
```

So far I have this

```
public string GetFullName(string source, string path)
{
    string formatPrefix = "Date";
    string regex = string.Format("{{{0}(:([^}}]*))?}}", formatPrefix);
    string replacement = @"(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(regex);
    string result = rgx.Replace(source, replacement);
    FileInfo[] filePath = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles();
    var Filename = filePath.FirstOrDefault().Name;
    var matches = Regex.Matches(Filename, result);
    if (matches.Count == 1)
    {
        return Filename;
    }
    return "";
}
```

So here I pass the filename & path from the config file and it compares if there is a file in the folder that matched with the name and `DateTime`format set in the config file.
So far it work but because the regex is hard coded it only search for a `mmmYYYY` date format, what about if in the config file I set a new filename format such as `{Date:ddmmyyyy}_Finance.csv`. The current regex wont work.

My question here Is there other more elegant way to achieve this? I tried to use  `Directory.Getfiles()` with some search pattern filters, but have had no luck.

Thanks in advance for any info

Comment: Do you know your replacement contains a regex pattern? You just need to match all what is inside `{...}` and get the date, then parse it with `DateTime.TryParse`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have any sample please?. Thank you Wiktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code above, you are looking for files with the FinanceMMMyyyy.csv pattern. Then you retrieve the first file found. The following code is more readable. I'd like to avoid Regex if possible for this reason.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

var MONTH_CHARS = 3;
var YEAR_CHARS = 4;
var FILE_NAME = "Finance";

string filePattern = @"Finance*.csv";
string path = @"c:\temp\";



    foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(path, filePattern))
{
    var startIndex = FILE_NAME.Length;
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var month = fileName.Substring(startIndex, MONTH_CHARS);
    var year = fileName.Substring(startIndex + MONTH_CHARS, YEAR_CHARS);

    Console.WriteLine(fileName + "," + month + year);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(month) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(year)) continue;

    //Check for proper month and year here

    resultingFileName = fileName;

    break;
}

Console.WriteLine(resultingFileName);
```

You can do the following for the case where the date is at the beginning of the file name:

```
 var MONTH_CHARS = 2;
 var YEAR_CHARS = 4;
 var FILE_NAME = "Finance";


 string filePattern = @"*Finance.csv";
 string path = @"c:\temp\";
 var resultingFileName = "";
 var startIndex = 0;

 foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(path, filePattern))
 {

     var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

     var year = fileName.Substring(startIndex , YEAR_CHARS);
     var month = fileName.Substring(YEAR_CHARS, MONTH_CHARS);
     var endingFileName = fileName.Substring(YEAR_CHARS + MONTH_CHARS);


     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(month) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(year) || 
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(endingFileName)) continue;

     //Check for proper month and year here

     resultingFileName = fileName;

     break;
 }

 Console.WriteLine(resultingFileName);
```

Comment: Thank you Ernesto for your comment. I don't like regex too. Before this new requirement it was easy. In the config manager I had filename and its path and I combined them in order to get the full path. Now with this new requierement I have the filename plus the timestamp( ie: Finance{Date:mmYYYY}.csv. I cannot combinated them anymore because I have to parse that timestamp first and then seach if there is a file in the folder that match with the filaname set in the config. What happned if inthe config manager I change the filaname to {Date:yyyymm}Finance.csv.

Comment: Thanks again Ernesto. I'm sorry but I said on my comment that the timestamp could me move around the filename. This is why  we introduced the config file. In that file the user can specified the name and where the timestamp is located. For instance today user needs pick only Feb2015Finance.csv. So he/she set in the config file {Date:mmyyyy}Finance.csv. In one week he/she needs Finance{Date:mmyyyy}.csv. The end users are not programmer. They just make change in the config file to set the desired file to read. Thanks again Ernesto.

Answer (score 0):

After normalising the format so it matches .Nets (e.g. `mm` => `MM`), try and convert the last part of the file to a date in the given format:

```
string mask   = "ddMMyyyy";
string egFile = "Finance_01052016.csv";

if (egFile.Length >= mask.Length) {
    string possibleDate = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(egFile).Substring(mask.Length);

    DateTime dateTime;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(possibleDate, mask, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime)) {
        Console.Write("{0} is {1}", egFile, dateTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for your comment. And what happened if in the config file the filename change to {Date:YYYYMM}Finance.csv. Because the user can make changes in the config file i order to pickup the correct file. Today could be {Date:yyyymm}Finance.csv but tomorrow could be Finance{Date:yyyymm}.csv and I only have to pick the file specified in the config file. Thank you.